# Problum auto redirected to the original script/indicator

Tags: javascript, pine-script, chatgpt-api

I just edited one of the existing indicator scripts and added an alert function to it without disrupting other parts of the script. However, when I added the modified script to the chart, the TradingView immediately redirected to the original script/indicator. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

I hope someone give me solution

Comment: I'd love to know more about what you are trying to do if you still want help

Answer (score 0):

First delete the existing indicator from your chart
then add your modified indicator to your chart.